# Debugging a concrete pixel in VS 2013 Graphics Debugging Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2013, shader, pixel, direct3d

While using the graphics debugging tool in VS 2013 is it possible to choose and step-by-step debug a concrete pixel in the pixel shader? No matter which pixel I select using the crosshair in the captured frame, the pixel which is analyzed while stepping in the pixel shader is always the same (the interpolated texture coordinates do not change for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pixel history, expand the -> and you can select from different vertices (and pixels) and step through a particular one.  If you don't, you'll always get the corner pixel first.  So, if you want one in the middle, expand a different arrow under the history.